# How can I place a still image before the first frame of a video?

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg, splash-screen, poster

When I encode videos by FFMpeg I would like to put a jpg image before the very first video frame, because when I embed the video on a webpage with "video" html5 tag, it shows the very first picture as a splash image. Alternatively I want to encode an image to an 1 frame video and concatenate it to my encoded video. I don't want to use the "poster" property of the "video" html5 element.

Answer (score 32):

You can use the concat filter to do that. The exact command depends on how long you want your splash screen to be. I am pretty sure you don't want an 1-frame splash screen, which is about 1/25 to 1/30 seconds, depending on the video ;)

### The Answer

First, you need to get the frame rate of the video. Try `ffmpeg -i INPUT` and find the `tbr` value. E.g.

```
$ ffmpeg -i a.mkv
ffmpeg version N-62860-g9173602 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Apr 30 2014 21:42:15 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
[...]
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'a.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf55.37.101
  Duration: 00:00:10.08, start: 0.080000, bitrate: 23 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive), yuv444p, 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
At least one output file must be specified
```

In the above example, it shows `25 tbr`. Remember this number.

Second, you need to concatenate the image with the video. Try this command:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate FPS -t SECONDS -i IMAGE \
       -t SECONDS -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0 \
       -i INPUTVIDEO \
       -filter_complex '[0:0] [1:0] [2:0] [2:1] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1' \
       [OPTIONS] OUTPUT
```

If your video doesn't have audio, try this:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate FPS -t SECONDS -i IMAGE \
       -i INPUTVIDEO \
       -filter_complex '[0:0] [1:0] concat=n=2:v=1:a=0' \
       [OPTIONS] OUTPUT
```

`FPS`     = `tbr` value got from step 1

`SECONDS` = duration you want the image to be shown.

`IMAGE`   = the image name

`INPUTVIDEO` = the original video name

`[OPTIONS]` = optional encoding parameters (such as `-vcodec libx264` or `-b:a 160k`)

`OUTPUT` = the output video file name

### How Does This Work?

Let's split the command line I used:

`-loop 1 -framerate FPS -t SECONDS -i IMAGE`: this basically means: open the image, and loop over it to make it a video with `SECONDS` seconds with `FPS` frames per second. The reason you need it to have the same FPS as the input video is because the `concat` filter we will use later has a restriction on it.

`-t SECONDS -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0`: this means: generate silence for SECONDS (0 means silence). You need silence to fill up the time for the splash image. This isn't needed if the original video doesn't have audio.

`-i INPUTVIDEO`: open the video itself.

`-filter_complex '[0:0] [1:0] [2:0] [2:1] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1'`: this is the best part. You open file 0 stream 0 (the image-video), file 1 stream 0 (the silence audio), file 2 streams 0 and 1 (the real input audio and video), and `concat`enate them together. The options `n`, `v`, and `a` mean that there are 2 segments, 1 output video, and 1 output audio.

`[OPTIONS] OUTPUT`: this just means to encode the video to the output file name. If you are using HTML5 streaming, you'd probably want to use `-c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a libfdk_aac (or -c:a libfaac) -b:a 128k` for H.264 video and AAC audio.

### Further information

- You can check out the documentation for the [`image2` demuxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1) which is the core of the magic behind `-loop 1`.
- Documentation for [`concat` filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) is also helpful.
- Another good source of information is the [FFmpeg wiki on concatenation](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20%28join%2C%20merge%29%20media%20files#filter).

Comment: Thx, it works. But how can I pass the other filters I usually use with the -vf option: ffmpeg says -vf and -filter_complex can't be used together.

Comment: What filters are you using? For `scale`, you have to first scale the image before `concat`ing it. For `fps` or others that change FPS, you have to use the new FPS for the `-r` option.

Comment: I am using this filter chain for the video: -vf 'crop=X:Y:W:Z, mp=eq2=1.35:1.02:0.05:1.04:1.0:1.0:1.0, scale=384:-1, setsar=1'

Comment: Is there a way to fade in/out the splash screen? @TimothyGu

Comment: For the above commands - do the image and video have to be the same size? Or is it possible to override this with a command?

Comment: @Damien Yes; but you could insert a `scale` filter specifically for the image-video to scale it up/down.

Comment: thanks so much for this! without any additional commands the image has to have the same dimensions, yes. amazing, thanks :)

Comment: @TimothyGu btw, what would the command look like to apply the audio and video codec from the input video in the output? i cant get it to work

Comment: scale and setsar are must to concatenate the image with the video. Eg: [1:v]scale=854:480, setsar=1:1[x];[x][2:a][0:v][0:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v][a]

Comment: Since Edit queue is full, I write this here:
- If you are on Windows, you need to delete the `\ ` from code.
- You may also need to remove quotations around the `-filter_complex`.
example command: `ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 23.98 -t 2 -i cover.jpg -t 2 -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0 -i vid.mp4 -filter_complex [0:0][1:0][2:0][2:1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 final.mp4`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is how I added two images before my video: `fmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 29.97 -t 1.5 -i vac1.jpg -t 1.5 -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0 -loop 1 -framerate 29.97 -t 1.5 -i vac2.jpg -t 1.5 -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0 -i vac_ts.mkv -filter_complex '[0:v:0][1:a:0] [2:v:0][3:a:0] [4:v:0][4:a:0] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1' OPTIONS out.mkv`

Comment: I had to use double quotes instead of single to make this work, but otherwise good. Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

The answer above works for me but in my case it took too much time to execute (perhaps because it re-encodes the entire video). I found another solution that's much faster. The basic idea is:

1. Create a "video" that only has the image.
2. Concatenate the above video with the original one, without re-encoding.

**Create a video that only has the image:**

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -i image.jpg -c:v libx264 -t 3 -pix_fmt yuv420p image.mp4
```

Note the `-framerate 30` option. It has to be the same with the main video. Also, the image should have the same dimension with the main video. The `-t 3` specifies the length of the video in seconds.

**Convert the videos to MPEG-2 transport stream**

According to the ffmpeg official documentation, only certain files can be concatenated using the concat protocal, this includes the MPEG-2 transport streams. And since we have 2 MP4 videos, they can be losslessly converted to MPEG-2 TS:

```
ffmpeg -i image.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts image.ts
```

and for the main video:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts video.ts
```

**Concatenate the MPEG-2 TS files**

Now use the following command to concatenate the above intermediate files:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:image.ts|video.ts" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4
```

Although there are 4 commands to run, combined they're still much faster then re-encoding the entire video.

Comment: Worked amazing! All steps itself execute in an instant, no re-encoding. But involves a lot of manual work. **Could someone please put this together into a script which does all this in one pass and cleans up the auxillary ".ts" files afterwards?** I imagine it like this: `insertStillframeToMP4.sh -p <durationInSecs> <picFile> -v <videoFile> -o <outputFile>`. The argument order of `-p` and `-v` determines whether the pic gets inserted before or after the video. The framerate is read out from the <videoFile> with some `ffmpeg -i | grep parseFPSexpression`.

Comment: Nice :-) this allows me to apply filters to the image and the video separately before concatenating them. Trying to do it all at once, like in Timothy's answer, gave errors which I wasn't able to fix.

Comment: btw, you could update this to use h265. Just change `libx264` to `libx265` in the first command, and `h264_mp4toannexb` to `hevc_mp4toannexb` everywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

My solution. It sets an image with duration of 5 sec before the video along with aligning video to be 1280x720. Image should have 16/9 aspect ratio.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i image.png -filter_complex '
       color=c=black:size=1280x720 [temp]; \
       [temp][1:v] overlay=x=0:y=0:enable='between(t,0,5)' [temp]; \
       [0:v] setpts=PTS+5/TB, scale=1280x720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease, pad=1280:720:-1:-1:color=black [v:0]; \
       [temp][v:0] overlay=x=0:y=0:shortest=1:enable='gt(t,5)' [v]; \
       [0:a] asetpts=PTS+5/TB [a]'
-map [v] -map [a] -preset veryfast output.mp4
```

Comment: The only command that worked for me! Could be documented a little better