# FFMPEG: how to include a splash screen?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, jpeg

Having a video file, I want to add at its beginning and end a JPEG file to be shown a few (say 10) seconds.

The time the image is shown should **not** be subtracted from the "main" video time. Instead the length of the video should be increased for the period the images are shown.

How to do this with FFMPEG?

The suggestions how to make it fade in/out or to do other graphical effects are appreciated.

Comment: I did this with MoviePy. I do not need FFMPEG anymore

Comment: Close the question if you aren't looking for answers anymore.

Comment: @Mulvya I don't think it should be closed. The question may be interesting for other users

Comment: This is duplicate question.
Read this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/24111474/4983086