# How to place a still image before a video stream

Tags: ffmpeg

My question has been answered, see this thread:
[How can I place a still image before the first frame of a video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102336/how-can-i-place-a-still-image-before-the-first-frame-of-a-video)
Unfortunately, the non-audio solution is not working for me.
I have an input BMP file, and input CINE file [written by Vision Research SDK], and wish to produce an output MP4 file.
I pass the following command:

ffmpeg -y -r 100 -loop 1 -framerate 100 -t 1 -i c:\x.bmp -i c:\x.cine -filter_complex '[0:0] [1:0] concat=n=2:v=1:a=0' c:\x.mp4

And get error message:

[AVFilterGraph @ 000000000346be80] No such filter: '[0:0]'
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument

Is the original thread answer for non-audio mistaken?
Or have I not exactly done what the original thread answer suggests?

Comment: Share full log. Add `-report` to your command.

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/ffmpeg-20180817-123307